# How to change what I chose in Visual Studio's first-time-wizard?

Tags: visual-studio, themes, wizard

When you launch Visual Studio for the first time, you get a wizard where you can select a "theme". I would like to change my selection, but I can't seem to find a way to re-run the wizard, or options which are similar to the wizard's options.

Specifically I use Visual Studio 2010 and have chosen a classical theme instead of a Visual theme for web development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the menu command `Tools -> Import and Export settings...`. Then follow the instructions:

- Select `Import selected environment settings`, click Next
- Select whether to make a backup of current settings or not. Click Next.
- Select the default setting you want from the list, click Next
- Select what specific settings to include (if you don't want all of them). Click Finish.